# Unable to run Synergy on Kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux, synergy

So I was able to install Synergy on Kali by downloading the .deb file from their Website. When I run it the windows pops up and I can input my server IP from my main PC, but when I click "start" I get this message here that just floods the log.

`[2017-07-03T23:27:48] INFO: starting server
[2017-07-03T23:27:48] INFO: config file: /tmp/qt_temp/.hX1753
[2017-07-03T23:27:48] INFO: log level: INFO /usr/bin/synergys: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2017-07-03T23:27:48] ERROR: process exited with error code: 127
[2017-07-03T23:27:48] INFO: detected process running, auto restarting`

I know that error 127 means its trying run a command it doesn't know. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to do the same thing today, realised that both the Debian build on their website as well as the compilation from source instructions are insufficient for Kali Linux 2017.1.

Building from source with [their instructions](https://github.com/symless/synergy/wiki/Compiling) gives rise to something like the following error, which is probably due to a different version of OpenSSL expected from Synergy:

```
Building CXX object src/lib/net/CMakeFiles/net.dir/SecureSocket.cpp.o
synergy/src/lib/net/SecureSocket.cpp: In member function ‘void SecureSocket::showSecureCipherInfo()’:
synergy/src/lib/net/SecureSocket.cpp:810:46: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘SSL {aka struct ssl_st}’
  STACK_OF(SSL_CIPHER) * cStack = m_ssl->m_ssl->session->ciphers;
                                              ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/comp.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:47,
                 from /root/synergy/src/lib/net/SecureSocket.cpp:27:
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:144:16: note: forward declaration of ‘SSL {aka struct ssl_st}’
 typedef struct ssl_st SSL;
                ^~~~~~
src/lib/net/CMakeFiles/net.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'src/lib/net/CMakeFiles/net.dir/SecureSocket.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/lib/net/CMakeFiles/net.dir/SecureSocket.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:549: recipe for target 'src/lib/net/CMakeFiles/net.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/lib/net/CMakeFiles/net.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Going back to: /synergy
Error: make failed: 512
```

Following [this lead](https://symless.com/forums/topic/2630-openssl-110e-support-problem/), I found that the Synergy team reported that it has been fixed in the v1.9 branch (from their reply on 15 May 2017).

Turns out that their stable release is still at 1.8.8, which means you have to install the development 1.9 branch.

---

### Full instructions with comments

```bsh
# Clone their git repo
git clone https://github.com/symless/synergy-core
cd synergy

# Switch to v1.9 dev branch
git checkout v1.9

# Install dependencies from their compilation guide
apt-get install build-essential cmake libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev lintian python qt4-dev-tools xorg-dev fakeroot

# Install other dependencies required from CMakeLists
apt-get install libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev qtbase5-dev

# Create Makefile
cmake .

# Make and install
make
make install

# Run Synergy!
/usr/local/bin/synergy
```

There might be a few more dependencies missing here, but I can't be fully sure because I fumbled around this for quite a bit.

Finally, add the Synergy application to your launchers:

```bsh
# Edit the launcher file
nano /usr/local/share/applications/synergy.desktop

# Change the path from /usr/bin to /usr/local/bin:
Path=/usr/local/bin
Exec=/usr/local/bin/synergy
```

Then restart GNOME with Alt-F2 and type `r`. You should be able to find Synergy in the launcher (with a new icon from v1.9).

---

**EDIT**: Updated URL of GitHub repo from [symless/synergy](https://github.com/symless/synergy) to [symless/synergy-core](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core).

Comment: Thanks! Did this work and help. I was also able to just do "sudo apt-get install synergy" and that did get it working. Worked better than trying to install it through the websties version.

Answer (score 0):

The key line here is the program not being able to find libssl.so.1.0.0.

[An example search](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=libssl.so%20not%20found)

Make sure its installed and updated.

`apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev`

Add synlinks at the appropriate places.

`cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10`

If that doesn't work you can use strace to find where the libssl is being called.

`strace Synergy`